# App does not work on real device

Tags: iphone, ios

Here is the situation.

Device: ipod Touch 3rd generation. iOS 4.1
OS X: Lion

This is a very simple App, a ViewController, there is a UIImageView and a UIButton on it.  When clicking the button, it would do some computing, generate a image and load it to the UIImageView. Generally speaking, when you click the button, it would do some image processing working in the click event.

This App works well on the simulator. It would display a picture on the UIImageView correctly when you click the button. It costs about 1~2 seconds, not so long.

I connect my ipod touch to my MBP, and load it from Xcode. I set some break points in one `for` loop in my code (in click event). There is some strange things.

This `for` loop is the main loop which do the most of the computing. It would stop at the break point at first, the i is 0 `i=0`; When I continue the app, the app seems stop, you need wait for a while, then the i becomes 4 or 8 or 9, not the correct number which is `1`.

I suspect, if I put the computing work in another thread, not in the UI thread. Does it help? Actually, there is nothing strange code in the click event, however, I can't get the correct images, only a black one. Does anyone meet it before, or please provide your suggestion.

***UPDATE***

Here is what the button click event doing.

```
int width=320;
    int height=480;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    void *imageData = malloc( height * width * 4 );
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );
    //CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    CGContextClearRect( contextRef, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ) );
    CGContextTranslateCTM( contextRef, 0, height - height );

    for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<width; j++) {
            *((char *)(imageData+i*width*4+j*4))=0;
            *((char *)(imageData+i*width*4+j*4+1))=0;
            *((char *)(imageData+i*width*4+j*4+2))=0;
            *((char *)(imageData+i*width*4+j*4+3))=255;
        }
    }

    int xmin=-2;
    int xmax=2;
    int ymin=-2;
    int ymax=2;

    int fre[320 * 480]={0};

    CGPoint p=CGPointZero;

    float x=arc4random()*1.0/ARC4RANDOM_MAX;
    float y=arc4random()*1.0/ARC4RANDOM_MAX;

    p.x=x*(xmax-xmin)+xmin;
    p.y=y*(ymax-ymin)+ymin;

    int MIN_ITERATE=10;
    int ite_from_start=0;

    DataPoint point;
    point.p=p;
    point.red=0.0;
    point.green=0.0;
    point.blue=0.0;

    IFSFunctions *ifsfunction=[[IFSFunctions alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        if(p.x<=160 && p.x >=-160 && p.y <= 240 && p.y >= -240)
        {
            //fre[((int)p.y+240)*320+(int)p.x+160]++;
                point=[ifsfunction caculate:point];

            int data_x=(int)(320*(point.p.x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin));
            int data_y=(int)(480*(point.p.y-ymin)/(ymax-ymin));

            if(data_x >=0 && data_x<320 && data_y >=0 && data_y < 480 && ite_from_start < 20000)
            {
                ite_from_start++;
                if(ite_from_start > MIN_ITERATE)
                {
                    *((char *)(imageData+data_y*width*4+data_x*4))=(int)point.red;
                    *((char *)(imageData+data_y*width*4+data_x*4+1))=(int)point.green;
                    *((char *)(imageData+data_y*width*4+data_x*4+2))=(int)point.blue;;
                }
                fre[data_y*width+data_x]++;
            }
            else
            {
                ite_from_start=0;
                point=[ifsfunction caculate:point];
            }
        }
    }

    int max_int=0;
    for (int i=0; i<320*480; i++) {
        if (fre[i]>max_int) {
            max_int=fre[i];
        }
    }
    //NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"The max interation %f",logf(max_int+1)]);
    for (int i=0; i<height; i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<width;j++){
            float intensity=logf(fre[i*width+j]+1.0)/logf(max_int/300+1);
            //NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"The %f",intensity]);
            float gamma=powf(intensity, 0.25);
            *((char *)(imageData+i*width*4+j*4))=(int)(gamma*(*((char *)(imageData+i*width*4+j*4))));
            *((char *)(imageData+i*width*4+j*4+1))=(int)(gamma*(*((char *)(imageData+i*width*4+j*4+1))));
            *((char *)(imageData+i*width*4+j*4+2))=(int)(gamma*(*((char *)(imageData+i*width*4+j*4+2))));
        }
    }

    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider=CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, imageData, height * width * 4, NULL);
    CGImageRef imageRef=CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, 4*width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big, dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), imageRef);

    imgView.image=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
    free(imageData);
```

Best Regards,

Comment: Please show us the code for the loop. Also, if there is an error message then please tell us what the error message says.

Comment: There is no error message, I want to show my code, however, it's hard to show them all

Comment: Then we can't help. How can we know what is happening if we can't see the code?

Comment: I will update the post to add code.

Comment: You have several for loops. Which for loop give you the incorrect value for i?

Comment: for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) maybe I did not express clearly. When I debug on the real device, it doesn't response like the simulator. If I set a break point here, it can stop it. Then I continue, the i don't increase immediately, it would wait for a while, however, the next i is not 1.

Answer (score 0):

If it takes 1~2 seconds on the simulator, it will take a lot more on a device. In fact, the simulator is just the iOS APIs on the Mac. I'd create an NSOperation and execute it on a separated thread. And make sure your for loop looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < YOURNUMBERHERE; i++)
```

Comment: Maybe less than 1 second, it seems quick. Do you mean if it runs in another thread may solve this issue?

Comment: Running in another thread will not solve the issue. It will still fail, but it will just fail in another thread.

Comment: I understand that, but my reading of the question indicates that something else is going one in the loop that keeps his app from working.